# Java Server side UnitTesting GCM's Result

Tags: java, junit, mockito, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in order to send notifications to an Android App. My server is using the Google provided `gcm-server.jar` and I'm following the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#server). I am able to send notifications without issue to a device.

Now I am trying to unit test business logic based on the [`Result`](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/index.html) ([source](https://gist.github.com/4197940)) returned from `PushNotificationDaoGcmImpl`'s private method `sendNotificationToServer`.

I know that `Result` cannot be Mocked due to it being a `final` class and that simply instantiating it as `new Result()` will not work because there are no public constructors. The `Result` inner `Builder` class is inaccessible outside of the `package com.google.android.gcm.server;` so I can not build the object that way.

I do not find a good way to create a `Result` which is what is being returned from the [`Sender`](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/index.html)([source](https://gist.github.com/4198106)).

My question is how would I go about unit testing that `PushNotificationDaoGcmImpl` handles certain conditions based on `Result`?

```
public class PushNotificationDaoGcmImpl{

    //method I'm trying to test
    public void sendPushNotification(){
        // builds message to send

        Result result = this.sendNotificationToServer(gcmMessage, deviceToken)

        //handle result's error conditions
    }

    //method call I'm trying to mock
    private Result sendNotificationToServer(Message gcmMessage, String deviceToken){
        return gcmSender.send(gcmMessage, deviceToken, 1);
    }
}   

//test snipet
@Test
public void testSendNotificationToServer () throws Exception {
    Result result = new Result();

    PushNotificationMessage message = new PushNotificationMessage("123", "Test", "deviceToken", "Android");

    //Having issue with how to handle Result here
    doReturn(result).when(gcmPushNotificationDaoSpy).sendNotificationToServer(any(Message.class), anyString());

    PushNotificationResult result = gcmPushNotificationDaoSpy.sendPushNotification(message);

    //verify business logic was correct based on Result
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create a MockResult class in the com.google.android.gcm.server package which will give you access to the Builder.

```
package com.google.android.gcm.server;

class MockResult {

    public static Result mockResult(...) {
      // Use Builder here to construct Result
    }

}
```

To me, this feels easier to manage than dealing with reflection.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I came to was to use reflection to create a `Result` object. I'm not sure if this is a great way to do it, but I'm able to test business logic based on different `Result` error codes.

```
@Test
public void testSendNotificationToServer () throws Exception {
    String successIndicator = null;
    Result result = buildFauxResult("messageId", "deviceToken", successIndicator);

    PushNotificationMessage message = new PushNotificationMessage("123", "Test", "deviceToken", "Android");

    //Having issue with how to handle Result here
    doReturn(result).when(gcmPushNotificationDaoSpy).sendNotificationToServer(any(Message.class), anyString());

    PushNotificationResult result = gcmPushNotificationDaoSpy.sendPushNotification(message);

    //verify business logic was correct based on Result
}

public Result buildFauxResult (String messageId, String canonicalRegistrationId, String errorCode) throws Exception {
           Class <?> builderClass = Class.forName("com.google.android.gcm.server.Result$Builder");
           Constructor <?> builderConstructor = builderClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
           ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(builderConstructor);
           Object builderObject = builderConstructor.newInstance();

           Method canonicalRegistrationIdMethod = builderClass.getMethod("canonicalRegistrationId", String.class);
           ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(canonicalRegistrationIdMethod);
           builderObject = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(canonicalRegistrationIdMethod, builderObject, canonicalRegistrationId);

           Method messageIdMethod = builderClass.getMethod("messageId", String.class);
           ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(messageIdMethod);
           builderObject = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(messageIdMethod, builderObject, messageId);

           Method errorCodeMethod = builderClass.getMethod("errorCode", String.class);
           ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(errorCodeMethod);
           builderObject = ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(errorCodeMethod, builderObject, errorCode);

           Method buildMethod = builderClass.getMethod("build");
           ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(buildMethod);

           return (Result) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(buildMethod, builderObject);
    }
```